# Casting to custom dictionary type

Tags: python, dictionary, casting

I am using a set of Json objects to create set of dictionaries like this.

```
t = [{"A":100}, {"B":200}, {"C":300}]
```

Now I want them to cast in to a bigger dictionay in such a way that items no specified should take a default value.

```
default = {
        "A" : 10,
        "B" : 20,
        "C" : 30
        }
```

What I have tried so far is to use a class as follows

```
class MyClass:
    default = {
            "A" : 10,
            "B" : 20,
            "C" : 30
            }

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.default.update(input)

    def get(self):
        return self.default
```

But when i try to create a list of dictionaries like this, it gives wrong answer.

```
a = [MyClass(x).get() for x in t]
[{'A': 100, 'C': 300, 'B': 200}, {'A': 100, 'C': 300, 'B': 200}, {'A': 100, 'C': 300, 'B': 200}]
```

seems to me like only one class instance was generated and the init was called upon it instead of creating many instances.
Can you please point out the error/suggest other ways of doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, mind showing the duplicate question ?

Comment: It is at the top of your question below your title.

Answer (score 1):

> seems to me like only one class instance was generated

Because that's exactly what happened. All instances of `MyClass` have the same reference to the same dictionary. You should instantiate a new dictionary in your constructor:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.default = {
            "A" : 10,
            "B" : 20,
            "C" : 30
        }
        self.default.update(input)

    def get(self):
        return self.default
```

Comment: Hi @Derek, Thanks for the answer. My background is C/C++, so I have a little hard time understanding this. Shouldn't each call to MyClass constructor supposed  to create new instances of the class MyClass. if not whats the purpose of having classes ?

Comment: @ABCD If you have knowledge of C++, in your initial code you have created a static attribute, and remember C++ is not python, they do not have the same syntax.

Comment: @ABCD Your code is equivalent to allocating memory for a dictionary structure, then initializing all `MyClass` to have a pointer pointing the same structure. You need to reallocate more memory for the structure in the constructor. That’s the same in both Python and C++.